# Groups exam question help

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Have this question, and am finding it pretty difficult:

[image]

I'm not sure about part (a) at all. Part (b) I got as far as showing it was non-empty. Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I can not see the image, Can one edit the question ?

Comment: @mesel It seems fine on my screen.

Comment: But I can see the image, I do not know the reason.

Comment: @mesel I uploaded it again. Can you see it now?

Comment: No, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(a) The "relationship" between the action $\ast$ and the homomorphism $\Phi$ is that every action induces a homomorphism (as described in the question), and vice-versa : Every homomorphism $\Phi : G\to S_Y$ gives an action of $G$ on $Y$ given by
$$
g\cdot y := \Phi(g)(y)
$$

(b) To prove $\Sigma(\ast)$ is a subgroup, it is enough to show that for $f,g \in \Sigma(\ast)$, $f\circ g^{-1} \in \Sigma(\ast)$. So note that
$$
\Phi_a = g\circ \Phi_a\circ g^{-1}
$$
Hence,
$$
g^{-1}\circ \Phi_a = \Phi_a\circ g^{-1}
$$
$$
\Rightarrow f\circ g^{-1} = f\circ \Phi_a\circ g^{-1} = \Phi_a\circ f\circ g^{-1}
$$
whence $f\circ g^{-1} \in \Sigma(\ast)$

Comment: Understood, thank you.